# Google Sheets Script: Getting values between two values?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
var mySTR = "some text some text some text1 text some text1 some text, some text some text text1 some other text text2 some text."




// i want as result: all text bewteen last appearing "text1" and "text2"

var result = "text1 some other text text2"
```

How can i solve this ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mySTR.slice(mySTR.lastIndexOf('text1')+5,mySTR.lastIndexOf('text2'));`

```
function textbetween(ss1,ss2,s) {
  var ss1=ss1||'text1';
  var ss2=ss2||'text2';
  var s=s||"some text some text some text1 text some text1 some text, some text some text text1 some other text text2 some text."
  Logger.log(s.slice(s.lastIndexOf(ss1)+ss1.length,s.lastIndexOf(ss2)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that just looks for the position of the two delimiters in the string. Than you can extract the text in between those two positions.

You can use the `string.lastIndexOf()` function to find the last match. Once you have the two indices, you can use the `string.splice()` function to extract the part out of the string.

A quick fiddle to show what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_I_Am/5aq4tucp/28/